# How do you prevent a multiline textbox from scrolling when text is added?

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline

I have a multiline TextBox called Console.  While running, this textbox is being filled up with some communications data.  I use

```
TextBox.AppendText("txt\r\n");
```

to add a line to it and that allows me to have it autoscroll down.  My problem is I want to be able to not have it autoscroll down.  So I thought I would try

```
TextBox.Text += "text";
```

But that scrolls you to the beginning of the box.  My latest attempt was to use TextBox.SelectionStart to save the position before I wrote and restore it back to that after, but that didn't seem to make a difference and still brings me back to the beginning of the text.

```
int txtPosition = Console.SelectionStart;
Console.Text += "TextToAdd";
Console.SelectionStart = txtPosition;
```

Ideally I want to just be able to have the box stay where ever it happens to be and not scroll to the beginning or end of the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to you a **richtextbox** instead of a generic textbox and this will provide you with the functionality you desire.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.  Have some other issues now, but slowly working through them.

Answer (score 1):

For a WinForms textbox, you may should able to do this:

```
textBox.SelectionStart = 0; 
textBox.ScrollToCaret(); // force current position back to top
```